# XMLHttpRequest объясните что не так

Tags: javascript, html, html5, xmlhttprequest

Не могу понять что не так, где не правильная запись.

```
function login() {
let auth = document.getElementById('auth');
let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
let err = document.createElement("P");
err.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Email or password is incorrect"));
let notification = auth.appendChild(err);

if(email !== 'user@example.com' || password !== '123'){
    return alert(email+","+password);
}else {
  let URL = "/someURL";
//URL другой, может быть в нем проблема, если да, то как узнать
  let user ={
    email:email,
    password: password
  };

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange',() => {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
      if(xhr.status == 200){
        alert('done')
      }else{
        alert('wrong')
      }
    }
  });
  xhr.open("POST",URL,true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(user))

}
```

}

Comment: xhr.send(JSON.stringify(user)) точку с запятой упустили

Comment: @maximpoddubny не в этом дело, сейчас проверил и он в консоль выводит ошибку XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "URL который мне нужен" в чем проблема?

Comment: можно спросить, зачем вам return  -> `return alert(email+","+password);`

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич это просто проверка, для себя, на деле там появляется блок с сообщением об ошибке